# Identifying a ransomware with .mkp file extensions

Tags: ransomware, identification

Yesterday, a ransomware hit my PC. I didn't pay the ransom and didn't comply with what the attackers were asking for and I wiped everything and every drive on my PC and then reinstalled my stuff from a backup I made previously so everything is fine. But before I wiped everything, I backed up some of the files that were encrypted by the ransomware to try and analyze them later. Now that everything is working as before, I am interested to know which ransomware infected my PC.
In every directories of my computer it created a file named `+README-WARNING+.txt` which contained the following text:

> ::: Greetings :::
>
> Little FAQ:
>
> .1.
> Q: Whats Happen?
> A: Your files have been encrypted. The file structure was not damaged, we did everything possible so that this could not happen.
>
> .2.
> Q: How to recover files?
> A: If you wish to decrypt your files you will need to pay us.
>
> .3.
> Q: What about guarantees?
> A: Its just a business. We absolutely do not care about you and your deals, except getting benefits. If we do not do our work and liabilities - nobody will cooperate with us. Its not in our >interests.
> To check the ability of returning files, you can send to us any 2 files with SIMPLE extensions(jpg,xls,doc, etc... not databases!) and low sizes(max 1 mb), we will decrypt them and send back to you. That is our guarantee.
>
> .4.
> Q: How to contact with you?
> A: You can write us to our mailboxes: helprequest@techmail.info or hope2honest@aol.com
>
> .5.
> Q: How will the decryption process proceed after payment?
> A: After payment we will send to you our scanner-decoder program and detailed instructions for use. With this program you will be able to decrypt all your encrypted files.
>
> .6.
> Q: If I don�t want to pay bad people like you?
> A: If you will not cooperate with our service - for us, its does not matter. But you will lose your time and data, cause only we have the private key. In practice - time is much more valuable than money.
>
> :::BEWARE:::
> DON'T try to change encrypted files by yourself!
> If you will try to use any third party software for restoring your data or antivirus solutions - please make a backup for all encrypted files!
> Any changes in encrypted files may entail damage of the private key and, as result, the loss all data.

Does anyone recognize this ransomware?
I don't see any names in it and therefore I don't know to whom it could belong.

Every file on my system got added `.[B4ACABE4].[helprequest@techmail.info].mkp`
For example a file named `text-file.txt` would be named `text-file.txt.[B4ACABE4].[helprequest@techmail.info].mkp` after the attack.

The wallpaper was replaced with an image saying that my PC was hacked and I had to pay to get my data back but I didn't see anywhere an executable file to decrypt the files or pay the ransom or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

`mkp` suggests that it is **Makop ransomware** mentioned in CISA's [Alert (AA21-287A)](https://www.cisa.gov/uscert/ncas/alerts/aa21-287a) from Oct 14, 2021.

> In September 2020, personnel at a New Jersey-based WWS facility discovered potential Makop ransomware had compromised files within their system.

According to [Digital Recovery](https://digitalrecovery.com/en/recover-data-ransomware-mkp/)

> MKP ransomware is a variant of the [Makop ransomware](https://digitalrecovery.com/en/recover-data-ransomware-makop/), which like
> other ransomware has strived to create a family/cartel.

and

> Makop ransomware has been expanding through its affiliate program,
> RaaS (Ransomware as a Service), a tactic that aims to seek partners to
> carry out attacks by only charging a commission on top of the ransom
> value. This tactic is intended to expand the attacks by bringing
> renown to the group.

A more technical analysis of [Makop ransomware](https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/16848-makop-ransomware) from Tomas Meskauskas (PCrisk.com) shows the similarities despite the extension has been changed with this variant. The letter is identical.

> Makop is a type of malware categorized as ransomware. It operates by
> encrypting data of infected systems and demanding payment for
> decryption tools/software. During the encryption process, all affected
> files are renamed according to this pattern: original filename, unique
> ID, cyber criminals' email address and the `.makop` extension.
>
> For example, a file named `1.jpg` would appear as something like
> `1.jpg.[EF7BE7BC].[makop@airmail.cc].makop`, and so on. After this
> process is finished, a text file named `readme-warning.txt` is created
> on the desktop.

There are plenty of variants including:

- `.vassago` ([Petrovic, Mar 2, 2021](https://twitter.com/petrovic082/status/1366669597764710402))
- `.dark` ([dnwls0719, Apr 2, 2021](https://twitter.com/fbgwls245/status/1377883082997428224))
- `.mkp` ([dnwls0719, Dec 3, 2021](https://twitter.com/fbgwls245/status/1466705464100802560))
- `.factfull` ([GrujaRS, Jan 20, 2022](https://twitter.com/GrujaRS/status/1484179072108220431))
- `.phmqdw`([PCrisk, Apr 12, 2022](https://twitter.com/pcrisk/status/1513762360321880065))